# Asking about some issues find it in Vba Macro

Tags: vba6

Please advise according to following issue below

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("X")) Is Nothing Then
```

Please your support Regarding to this issue

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("X")) Is Nothing Then
```